# Finish Button on Flow reloads iFrame holding VF Flow Component

Tags: visual-workflow, page-layout, console, custom-console-components

I have maxed out the number of console components I can utilize on a page layout (8). I currently use the flows in custom console component tabs.

To workaround this limitation, I have created tabs in HTML/JS and placed each flow in a tab of this subtab.

My issue is when I hit finish on the flow, the tab refreshes, but it refreshes to only display the flow that was finished, it does not show the HTML/Tabs and other flows that it does at page initiation.

Ex:

```
Console Component Right Sidebar Tabs:
Tab 1
-Flow 1
Tab 2
-Flow 2
Tab 3
-HTML/JS Tabs
--Flow 3
--Flow 4
--Flow 5
```

Upon hitting the finish button on Flow 3, Tab 3 will refresh, but will only show Flow 3. The same happens if I hit the finish button on Flow 4, Tab 3 will refresh, but will only show Flow 4 until the entire page is refreshed.

Any ideas on how to prevent the tab container from refreshing to just the flow  or force a refresh of the entire page on finish button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting concept. 
I can see a couple ways of handling this.  The best is probably to handle the flow's status change event in your Lightning component:

```
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
```

You could have it load the next flow, or an "all done" screen, or...endless possibilities  ;)

The other option is to use the one of the new(ish) "flow local actions" to control what happens at the end of the flow.  For your use case, handling the "finished" status in your javascript controller makes more sense to me, but Local Actions are worth a look.

[Summer’18: Flow Local Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-flow-local-actions-improved-debugger-and-more.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add the solution to my root problem, not the question asked, I was trying to display the same Visualforce Tab custom console components that are displayed on primary tabs on my subtabs tabs as well.

My solution was adding the console components tabs on the subtab page layout level and removing them from the primary tab assignment. The subtab assignment which displayed them on the primary tab level.